# javascript function only works on second click

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

i have a link that will call 3 js functions.
This is how i wrote the link :

```
echo "<td>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' 
    onclick=$('#f').window('open');
    $(window).scrollTop($('#f').offset().top-60);
    checkForMatch();

    data-id='$row[0]'data-integ='$row[1]'data-type='$row[2]'
    class='edit_conn'
    >Edit</a></td>";
```

the `onclick=$('#f').window('open');`will open a modal and work just fine.
the `$(window).scrollTop($('#e').offset().top-60);` will reposition the modal and also work just fine. 
however the `checkForMatch();` only work on second click (this one will disable input based on textbox value)

Any clue why the `checkForMatch();` function only work on second click ?
please pardon my potato english.

Edit :

here is how i wrote the `checkForMatch` function :

```
function checkForMatch() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("typeconn_edit");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("countryphone_edit");

    if (input1.value == 'mobile_Phone') {
    input2.disabled = true;
    } else {
    input2.disabled = false;
    }
    }
```

Edit2 :
The "f" is a jqueryUI modal window this is how its written :

```
 <div id="f" class="easyui-window formedit" title="Entry identity
 Connectivity" data-options="modal:true,closed:true,iconCls:'icon-save'">

        <?php include 'form_edit_conn.php'; ?>

        </div>
```

the "idconn_edit", "integconn_edit", "typeconn_edit"  are input textboxes

```
<input type="text" id="idconn_edit" name="id">
<input type="text" id="integconn_edit" name="integ_conn">
<input type="text" id="typeconn_edit" name="type_conn">
```

and this is how i pass values to those 3 textboxes :

```
(document).on("click", ".edit_conn", function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    var integ = $(this).data('integ');  
   $(".formedit #idconn_edit").val( id ); 
   $(".formedit #integconn_edit").val( integ ); 
   $(".formedit #typeconn_edit").val( type );

});
```

and the "countryphone_edit" is a selectbox

```
<select  id="countryphone_edit">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT Country_Name FROM tbl_country");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['Country_Name']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['Country_Name']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
      </select>
```

and sorry there's no 'e' i didnt realize that one since 'f' already on a good position.

Comment: put a console.log in  the `checkForMatch` and see its called by first click

Comment: Don't use so much code inside an inline attribute. It makes the html unreadable, hard to maintain, and prone to mistakes. Separate it to a js file and use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach a function

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE], it is hard to tell what is happening without `checkForMatch`. Please give us enough code to replicate the issue. You might also want to consider making the `onclick` handler a singe method instead of 3 statements.

Comment: @azad sorry but.. how do i do that ?

Comment: @JonP ok i will edit my question

Comment: Your example is still not complete, we have no `typeconn_edit`, `countryphone_edit`, `#f` or `#e`. Try using the `<>` button in the editor to create a complete, interactive example that has the same problem.

Comment: @jonP my fault, i'll edit it again

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

i added checkForMatch(); function on the passing values code (edit_conn)

```
(document).on("click", ".edit_conn", function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    var integ = $(this).data('integ');  
   $(".formedit #idconn_edit").val( id ); 
   $(".formedit #integconn_edit").val( integ ); 
   $(".formedit #typeconn_edit").val( type );
   checkForMatch();

});
```

i honestly dont understand why adding `checkForMatch();` there solved my problem, but i think thats enough. Ty guys